# Adding mlpack to gem5 results in build error

Tags: c++, scons, gem5, mlpack

I try to add the mlpack library to gem5 in order to conduct an experiment. I have installed successfully the mlpack library on my Ubuntu 18.04 system. Then added the following includes in one of my modules:

```
#include <mlpack/methods/sparse_autoencoder/sparse_autoencoder_impl.hpp>
#include <mlpack/prereqs.hpp>
```

Build fails when reaches mlpack with a strange error within gem5 logging.hh:

```
/usr/include/mlpack/core/util/prefixedoutstream.hpp: In constructor 'mlpack::util::PrefixedOutStream::PrefixedOutStream(std::ostream&, const char*, bool, bool)':
build/RISCV/base/logging.hh:155:36: error: expected identifier before 'do'
 #define exit_message(logger, ...)  do {                                                \
                                ^
build/RISCV/base/logging.hh:155:36: error: expected '{' before 'do'
```

A code snippet from logging.hh where the error line is located:

```
#define exit_message(logger, ...)  do {                                                    \
    base_message(logger, __VA_ARGS__);              \
    logger.exit_helper();                           \
} while (0)
```

It seems that the problem occurs due to the macro "fatal" that is defined 
in gem5: [logging.hh documentation](http://www.gem5.org/docs/html/logging_8hh.html#acad519418dbfdd70c1208711e609c80e)

This question remains unsolved since there might be a workaround for it.
I have already published this issue in gem5 mailing list.

Comment: Does the c++ compiler you're using support the correct version of c++ mlpack requires and/or are you specifying the correct flags to enable it?

Comment: Actually I didn't compile mlpack on my machine. I have installed it using apt-get install and using it as a system library.

Comment: I'd go check the website/github for mlpack and see which version of gcc is the minimum to compile/link the code.

Comment: I have consulted with mlpack developers, they didn't mention the version of gcc as a possible cause for this problem. I have also tried to compile mlpack aside and there was no problem with gcc 7.4 which is installed on the machine. gem5 requires gcc 4.8 or greater

Comment: O.k. I'd say go ask the gem community. It's very unlikely a SCons issue.  Also are you saying that gcc 7.4 is the default compiler (system installed), or that it's an additional compiler (not the default /usr/bin/gcc or /bin/gcc)

Comment: 7.4 is the default compiler for sure.

Comment: I'd suggest manually running the compile line but added -E to it. This will output the  preprocessor output to stdout then redirect to a file and take a look at the line(s) in question.